# Show Backbone Collection element in a Marionette region

Tags: layout, backbone.js, requirejs, marionette, region

I have a Backbone application running and working properly with requirejs. Now, I'm trying to make a migration to Marionette in order to have the code better organized.

I just want to show a model from a collection in a region, with two buttons in another region. I want to go to the next or previous model from that collection. And change its view on the model region.

But I don't know how to iterate over the collection and send its model to the view.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acor/sgTwJ/1/) with some simplified code with this situation.

html:

```
<div class="player"></div>

<script id="layout-template" type="text/template">
    <div class="modelView"></div>
    <div class="controls"></div>
</script>
<script id="model-region" type="text/template">
    <%=name%>
</script>
<script id="control-region" type="text/template">
    <button id="prev">Prev</button>
    <button id="next">Next</button>
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to do this with or without updating your applications routes?

Comment: Without updating application routes.

Comment: My most recent try (the problem is when I want to display a region inside the lyout's initialize method): http://jsfiddle.net/acor/2gjrg/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you are trying to coordinate events between two views on the same layout.  In this case I would recommend setting up a [Controller](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.controller.md).

Then you can register view [triggers](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md#viewtriggers) for on your controls view:

```
ControlsView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  // ...

  triggers: {
    "click #previous": "control:previous",
    "click #next": "control:next"
  }
});
```

An then in your controller you would instantiate your views and setup a handler for the controlView triggers to update the modelView.

```
var Router = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
  appRoutes: {
      "/": "start",
      "/:index" : "showModel"
  },
});

var Controller = Marionette.Controller.extend({

  initialize: function(){
    var self = this;
    this.controlsView = new ControlsView();
    this.modelView = new MainView();
    this.myCollection = new MyCollection();
    this.myIndex = 0;
    this.myCollection.fetch().then(function(){
      self.myIndex = 0;
    });
    this._registerTriggers();
  },
  start: function(){
    this.controlLayout.show(this.controlView);
    this.showModel();
  },
  showModel: function(index){
    index = index || this.index;
    this.modelView.model = myCollection.at(this.index);
    this.modelLayout.show(this.modelView);
  },
  showNext: function(){
    var max = this.myCollection.models.length;
    this.index = max ? 1 : this.index + 1;
    this.showModel();
  },
  showPrevious: function(){
    var max = this.myCollection.models.length;
    this.index = 0 ? max : this.index - 1;
    this.showModel();
  },
  _registerTriggers: function(){
    this.controlsView.on("control:next", this.showNext());
    this.controlsView.on("control:previous", this.showPrevious());
  }
}

var controller = new Controller();
var router = new Router({
  controller: Mod.controller
});
controller.start();
```

Using this approach allows you to decouple your views and collection. This will make your code reusable (using the controls view in a different context as an example).

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [CollectionView](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md) or [CompositeView](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.compositeview.md).

The `CollectionView` will loop through all of the models in the
specified collection, render each of them using a specified `itemView`,
then append the results of the item view's `el` to the collection view's
`el`.

A `CompositeView` extends from `CollectionView` to be used as a
composite view for scenarios where it should represent both a
branch and leaf in a tree structure, or for scenarios where a
collection needs to be rendered within a wrapper template.

Comment: Definitely the CollectionView is not what I need. CompositeView may work, but I don't find any example of use for my approach.